# Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice, each

I am using `slice()` function inside `$.each()` array. It shows this error when the first half of the array values have the same string. `$name` is coming from a button which always has a different value i.e `question1`, `question2`.

I tried when the array is like `var arr = ["question1Answer1", "question2Answer2"];` then function works OK but when I push more values starting with `question2` and want to remove these values than above error shows in the console.

```
    var arr = ["question1Answer1", "question2Answer2", "question2Answer3"];
    refreshArrange = function($name) {

      $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        var newStr = '';

        newStr = value.slice(0, 9);

        if(newStr == $name) {
          var ind = arr.indexOf(value);
          if (ind > -1) {
            arr.splice(ind, 1);
            console.log('working Ok');
          }

        }else {

        }

      });

      console.log(arr);
    }
```

I want to remove the 2nd and 3rd value of array because the coming value of `$name` is `question2`. I am splitting up the array values and compare the first half with `$name` and removing it. But this error occurs.
I don't know where the problem is.

Actually, I want to remove the values of the array which starts from the value of `$name`

I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I know I didn't explain the problem properly.

Comment: I cannot spot a single reason you're using jQuery instead of vanilla Javascript here.

Comment: When using jQuery u can access the vanilla HtmlElements by indexing into the object: `arr[0]`

Comment: totally agree with @connexo. Also, I didn't really get what you're trying to do but I think you're using `slice` wrong- newStr will be an array containing all array elements from beginning to 9th place, and newStr2 - from beginning to 10th place...

Comment: @efkah He's not using jQuery to select any elements. Just as a totally unnecessary additional layer of complexity.

Comment: also you probably want to work with $name inside your function: `  $.each($name, function(index, value) { ...` . @connexo i agree.

Comment: @afnan You are passing `arr` and `$name` both same. Why ? I think `$name` should not be an array.

Comment: @JaydeepMor both are not same, ``$name`` is coming from outside of the function on ``onclick()``. ``$name`` always has the value either ``question1`` or ``question2`` then I want to remove the value from array which starts from ``question1......`` if ``$name`` contains the value ``question1`` and remove the value which starts from ``question2...`` if ``$name`` contains the value ``$question2``. ``$name`` is not an array, its just a passing variable. When array contains only two values like ``question1Answer1, question2Answer2`` then ``splice`` works correctly but when three its not working.

Comment: @JaydeepMor this is a working fiddle...for each answer there is refresh button, when you click a answer twice and then refresh it, it will show slice error in console. why ? https://jsfiddle.net/afnan03/gsj9kych/

Comment: I got it, once the item has been spliced from the array, jQuery will still loop for the length of the original array. So it then returns ``Undefined``. UPVOTE

Answer (score 0):

Because you splice a array while using for `each` this array `arr.splice(ind, 1);`

You can try my code:

```
var arr = ["question1Answer1", "question2Answer2", "question2Answer3"];
var refreshArrange = function($name) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    // var newStr2 = '';

    var newStr = value.slice(0, 9);
    // newStr2 = value.slice(0, 10);

    if(newStr == $name) {

    }else {
      result.push(value)
    }

  });

  console.log(result);
}

refreshArrange('question2');
```

Then `result` variable is the result that you expect

Comment: this is a working fiddle...for each answer there is refresh button, when you click a answer twice and then refresh it, it will show slice error in console. why ? https://jsfiddle.net/afnan03/gsj9kych/